# Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm JWT Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt

```
client_secret1 = "123"
client_secret2 = '''
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
123
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
'''

payload = {
    "iss": f"{client_id}",
    "sub": f"{client_id}",
    "aud": f"{token_endpoint}",
    "jti": "daflifnsorf",
    "exp": 60*5
}

jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, key=client_secret2, algorithm="RS384").decode()
```

This is what I have tried and I am getting the following error. Why could this be happening and what's the fix for this? Also, is client_secret1 in the incorrect formatting and won't fly?

ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=75497572, lib=9, reason=100, reason_text=bad base64 decode)>])

Comment: At first, I thought you had redacted the key data, but if you get such an error, can I assume this is your actual key shown in the code above? That's not a valid RSA key.  RSA Keys have a special format and can be created by code, with tools like open-ssl or with online tools like [this one](https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/). RSA Keys also come in pairs of public and private key.